# Using spread() in tidyr to pivot and drop NAs

Tags: r, tidyr

I am using R and I have data like

```
California | Los Angeles  
California | San Diego  
California | San Francisco  
New York | Albany  
New York | New York City
```

which I would like to transform to

```
California | New York  
Los Angeles | Albany  
San Diego | New York City  
San Francisco | NA
```

I am trying to use `spread()` in `tidyr` but can't quite get it to give me the output the way I need it. The closest I can come is

```
California | New York  
Los Angeles | NA  
San Diego | NA  
San Francisco | NA  
NA | Albany  
NA | New York City
```

Can someone please help me get it in the desired format?

Comment: The output you get (I assume from `spread(df, col1, col2)`) is exactly what you would expect from `tidyr`.

Comment: `v2 <- split(df$v2, df$v1) ; 
data.frame(lapply(v2, function(x){c(x, rep(NA, max(sapply(v2, length)) - length(x)))}))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it in base:

```
df<-data.frame(v1=c(rep("California",3), rep("New York",2)), v2=c("Los Angeles", "San Diego", "San Franciso", "Albany", "New York City"))

cali<-as.character(df[df$v1=="California", 2])
ny<-as.character(df[df$v1=="New York", 2])

new <- data.frame(California=cali, NewYork=c(ny, NA))

new
    California       NewYork
1  Los Angeles        Albany
2    San Diego New York City
3 San Franciso          <NA>
```